python asyncio.run inside reused method
In Python, whenever I see examples asyncio.run() usage it is inside a main function.
I have this scenario in my Flask application:
A request goes through:
MyController → MyService → MyRepository
I have these methods inside MyService class.
class MyService():

   def my_function():
     ...
     result = asyncio.run(self._get_all_async(items))
     ...
     return result



    async def _get_all_async(self, items: list):
        tasks = []

        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            for i in items:
                tasks.append(repository.my_function_with_requests_async(i, session))

            done, pending = await asyncio.wait(fs=tasks, timeout=3, return_when=FIRST_EXCEPTION)

            for p in pending:
                p.cancel()

            if not done and pending:
                raise TimeoutError("There are pending tasks to execute")

            result = []
            for d in done:
                result.extend(d.result())

            if pending:
                raise TimeoutError("There are pending tasks to execute")

            return result

MyService.my_function is a function called by every request coming from a @route. I would like to make async operation only in this part of the code, the others keep sync.
Everything is working, but I have questions.
I have found this on documentation of asyncio.run:

This function always creates a new event loop and closes it at the end.
It should be used as a main entry point for asyncio programs, and should
ideally only be called once.

So I guess I should not use asyncio.run inside this function

Should I share an instance of an event loop and reuse it?

If I were to create a shared event loop instance, where should it be placed?


